# Цвета COLORREF winapi

Tags: winapi

У меня есть `COLORREF color`. Как изменить отдельный атрибут: `R`, `G` или `B`?

Answer (score 3):

Для установки отдельного компонента необходимо сначала очистить соответствующий байт (первый для R, второй для G, третий для B) через побитовое И, затем записать новое значение через побитовое ИЛИ. Для удобства можно создать макросы:

```
#define SetRValue(c, r) ((COLORREF)((c & 0x00FFFF00) | ((BYTE)(r))))
#define SetGValue(c, g) ((COLORREF)((c & 0x00FF00FF) | ((BYTE)(g) << 8)))
#define SetBValue(c, b) ((COLORREF)((c & 0x0000FFFF) | ((BYTE)(b) << 16)))
```

Использование:

```
COLORREF color = RGB(0x11, 0x22, 0x33);
printf("0x%08x\n", color); // 0x00332211

color = SetRValue(color, 0xaa);
printf("0x%08x\n", color); // 0x003322aa

color = SetGValue(color, 0xbb);
printf("0x%08x\n", color); // 0x0033bbaa

color = SetBValue(color, 0xcc);
printf("0x%08x\n", color); // 0x00ccbbaa
```

Answer (score 3):

Для модификации отдельно взятого компонента сначала необходимо разбить исходный цвет на составлющие с помощью `Get*Value()`, затем собрать обратно с помощью `RGB()`, внося по ходу сборки необходимые модификации:

```
COLORREF changeRedColor(COLORREF oldColor, unsigned char newRed)
{
    return RGB(newRed, GetGValue(oldColor), GetBValue(oldColor));
}

COLORREF changeGreenColor(COLORREF oldColor, unsigned char newGreen)
{
    return RGB(GetRValue(oldColor), newGreen, GetBValue(oldColor));
}

COLORREF changeBlueColor(COLORREF oldColor, unsigned char newBlue)
{
    return RGB(GetRValue(oldColor), GetGValue(oldColor), newBlue);
}
```

Стоит отметить, что данный приём прекрасно оптимизируется компиляторами, превращаясь в побитовые И, ИЛИ и (если необходимо) сдвиг:

```
; gcc -O2 -m32 -S

changeRedColor(unsigned int, unsigned char):
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+8]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        and     edx, 16776960
        or      eax, edx
        ret

changeGreenColor(unsigned int, unsigned char):
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+8]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        movzx   ecx, dl
        and     edx, 16711680
        sal     eax, 8
        or      eax, ecx
        or      eax, edx
        ret

changeBlueColor(unsigned int, unsigned char):
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+8]
        movzx   edx, WORD PTR [esp+4]
        sal     eax, 16
        or      eax, edx
        ret
```